# Draw transparent lines with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I would like to draw lines and polygons with transparent lines in PDFBox. Here is some sample code of how I am drawing a blue line, but I cannot figure out to change the alpha value of the color.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();  
PDPage page = new PDPage();  
document.addPage(page);  
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);  
contentStream.setStrokingColor(66, 177, 230);  
contentStream.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot use the alpha value of the `java.awt.Color` as PDFBox only uses the RGB value. As per javadoc of `public void setStrokingColor(Color color)` it just:

> Set the stroking color, specified as
>   RGB.

One option could be that you set the background color as the stroking color to make your line invisible.
**NOTE -** Invisible != Transparent (so you won't get the see through effect)

Comment: As the other answers to this question make clear, transparency is possible in PDF, even with PDFBox.

Answer (score 10):

As of PDFBox 2.0 `appendRawCommands` is deprecated.

```
    float alpha = 0.5f;
    PDExtendedGraphicsState graphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    graphicsState.setStrokingAlphaConstant(alpha);
    stream.setGraphicsStateParameters(graphicsState);
    // draw line here
```

Comment: Somehow this results in a NullPointerException in setGraphicsStateParameters()

Comment: null on the stream or null on the graphicsState object?  GraphicsState shouldn't be null as its being initialized right there.

Comment: the content stream has no resources. this probably depends on the code because sometimes resources are not needed but when the resources object is required by the content stream, it should be instantiated automatically. the solution would be to use stream.setResources(new PDResources());

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a custom extended graphics state:

```
PDExtendedGraphicsState graphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
graphicsState.setStrokingAlphaConstant(0.5f);
COSName graphicsStateName = page.getResources().add(graphicsState);
try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true)) {
    cs.appendRawCommands("/" + graphicsStateName.getName() + " gs\n");
    // draw your line here.
}
```