# C# PDFBox 1.8 Highlight text and navigate to that text in a browser?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox

Thanks in advance. I am using PDFBox 1.8. Q:Is there a way to highlight text in a PDF & when rendered in the browser move to that text & or page?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by move to that `text` or `page`? How will you move?

Comment: I would love to get right to the text, but on the page would be okay.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619737/create-pdf-file-with-default-zoom-to-page-level-pdfbox answers the second part of the question but in java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540593/draw-transparent-lines-with-pdfbox (the answer without the green checkmark) sortof answers the first part of the question (but in java), i.e. use a custom extended graphics state.